# How to align words vertically on the right, so that the texts are not in and out?

Tags: html, css

I am new to html and css and I am trying to create web page. My question is, how do I align words vertically on the right, so that the texts are not in and out? So this is the problem I am getting, shown in this pictrue[image].

I want it to look like this [image: the effect I want]

So basically I want the texts to align in a tidy way.

Comment: We need to see your code. Post a [mcve] in your question please

Comment: Wouldn't it have been much easier to type your question into Google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`text-align: justify;` will justify text in an element. You might also want to look at the [text-justify](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-justify.asp) property.

```css
p { text-align: justify; max-width: 200px; }
```

```html
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</p>
```